# Inheriting template instantiation of a nested type

Tags: c++

So I failed to find a way to get below compiled. Any possible workarounds?

```
#include <vector>

class A : public std::vector<A::B>
{
public:
    enum class B
    {
    };
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: What? How can you inherit from something that isn't defined yet? This is some crazy recursive inheritance mess.

Comment: @CoryKramer I thought I can forward declare the nested enum class and use it. But it appears I cannot. There's no reason why the compiler cannot handle this apart from what the standard defines. The exact size of the enum class is already known before the definition of `A` is complete.

Comment: No you cannot get away with a forward declaration. For you to instantiate a template specialization, e.g. `std::vector<T>` the type `T` must be *fully defined* at that point, not an incomplete type.

Comment: Why is it so important for B to be an inner `enum class`?
Maybe just put it in a namespace where both `A` and `B` live.

Comment: Why not make the vector a member variable?

Comment: _"The exact size of the enum class is already known before the definition of `A` is complete"_ It's not even known that `A::B` is a type, let alone an `enum class`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, I'm just about to do that. I wanted to inherit the vector because this class is somewhat container-like and I do need the `[]` operator preferably without redefining it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True. What I thought originally is that with some kind of forward delaration `enum class A::B` the compiler can deal with this because it's just an enum with no special members and the size of it should be the size of the underlying type.

Comment: @xiver77: But what's so bad about redefining it? It's just a one-liner (or two, for the `const` overload), delegating to the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull `B` inside a base class :

```
struct P {
    enum class B { /* ... */ };
};

struct A : P, std::vector<P::B> {
    using P::B;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. There is no way to use `A::B` without defining `A`.

From design point of view, deriving from the standard library containers is discouraged. If it's not too much trouble, I would recommend using:

```
class A
{
  public:
    enum class B
    {
    };
    std::vector<B> data;
};
```